# Detect if user denied or granted permission to an app and then process some code

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions, runtime

My app needs permission to read `external storage`,I have code in `OnCreate`method to self check if the permission is already granted and if not ask for it from the user, my problem is making the app aware of the user's choice... if user denies it then `activity.finishaffinity` should be called else the app should continue running...
here is he code i have so far....

```
class MyActivity:AppCompatActivity{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        checkpermission();
        }
      private void checkpermission(){
         if(ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this,Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage)
         !=Permission.Granted){
         //Permission is not granted so request one
          RequestPermisions(new string[]{Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage},1);
       
         }
      }
}
```

The code above works fine to self check for permission and request one, the only problem i have is detecting if a user granted it or denied it and then call `activity.FinishAffinity()`

Comment: You need to continue `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: i need to override an inbuilt method? how exactly i get to do that is my problem

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.platform.onrequestpermissionsresult?view=xamarin-essentials-android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.android+android-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **onRequestPermissionsResult** in activity

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
      case 101: {
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
          if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
          // when user denied permission
          } else {
           // when user allow permission
          }
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```